# ERROR Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza;

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am facing this issue from 2 days, still not found any solution.
I tried changing versions of libraries, clean and build project, and invalidate cache etc.

Below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.root.ambulancetracking"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is build.gradle (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is what i am getting in message window.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza;
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 22s
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried my level best

Please, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Can you add complete error traces what you are getting

Comment: i updated my question with error messages.

Comment: You need to enable multidex.

Comment: did it already.

Answer (score 0):

please add this lib to resolve this issue

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

also, enable multidex in your application class

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your version are conflict

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

covert to this lines :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same version of Firebase and Google Play Service if you're using google play service plugin below 3.3.0.

If you want to use multiple version of Firebase and Google Play Service (starting from version 15), you need to [use google play service plugin 3.3.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html). So, change your project `build.gradle` to:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

...
```

Last, don't forget to always add the following line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the *bottom* of your **app** build.gradle.